# While querying to get a user's information with queryEqualToValue, I can't get the user's info that has additional child's [Firebase][Swift]

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here's how the database looks like. I'm trying to query the logged in user's information but I can't seem to return the values that have additional children such as address and image. firstName and lastName seem to return fine.

[image: a busy cat]

Code:

```
if FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser != nil {
    let queryRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user")
    queryRef.queryEqualToValue(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
```

and these return nil

```
print(snapshot.value!.valueForKey("address")!.valueForKey("lineOne") as! String)
print(snapshot.value)
```

this returns a value though

```
print(snapshot.value!.valueForKey("firstName") as? String)
```

What am I doing wrong to not be able to return all the values? Changing .Value to .ChildAdded doesn't return anything at all.

This is code without query equal to value below is working fine though

```
let queryRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("user")
    queryRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) -> Void in


        self.userDict.append(snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.searchTableView.reloadData()
            print(self.userDict)
            SwiftLoader.hide()


            queryRef.removeAllObservers()

        })
    })
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out the issue?

Comment: Yeah, instead of queryEqualToValue, which would not work because the values have children under it, you just simply .child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of queryEqualToValue, you use .child(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid).